# Unable to update input value using keydown event

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I am writing a test case where I need to update input value using `keydown` event but I am unable to change the input value. Please help!

Following is the code that I have tried but it doesn't work.

```
import { Component } from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import numericOnly from '@/directives/input-numeric-only';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);

localVue.directive('numericOnly', numericOnly);

describe('Directives Input-Numeric-Only', () => {

let component: Component;
let wrapper: any;

beforeEach(() => {
    component = {
        template: `
            <input type="text" id="inputNumericOnly" v-numericOnly
                v-bind:value="inputValue" @input="updateInput($event)" />
        `,
        data() {
            return {
                inputValue: 0,
            };
        },
        methods: {
            updateInput($event: any) {
                console.log('Input Change....', $event.target.value);
            },
        },
    };
    wrapper = shallowMount(component, {
        localVue,
    });
});

it('Check if char key is pressed', () => {
    wrapper.find('input').trigger('keydown', {
        which: 65,
    });
    expect(wrapper.vm.inputValue).toBe('a');
});
});
```

I expect the input value to be changed but has no affect on it.

Comment: Can you try **@keydown.native="updateInput($event)"** instead of **@input="updateInput($event)"**